# Can we have multiple Normalizers in REST API?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I have a requirement of exposing multiple content type data via different REST end point. I am using Normalizers to create an array as expected. For one content type it works perfect but when i try to add another normalizer with different name, flow is not coming to new one rather its going to old normalizer itself as both are extending the same class i.e `ContentEntityNormalizer`. I was jut trying to separate each content type normalizer to achieve more readability of code instead of working on same normalizer. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: fwiw - I believe I had a similar question and was able to figure out how to get two+ REST normalizers from conflicting in this exchange: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307609/how-to-keep-similar-custom-services-from-conflicting/307614#307614